# Form validation is not a function - Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, formvalidation-plugin

I'm tying to use a bootstrap date picker based on this example:

http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-datepicker/

This is my .html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">         
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <!-- ################ -->
            <!-- ####Bootstrap### -->
            <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.4.5/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- ################ -->
        <!-- #####Custom##### -->           
        <script src="Scripts/datepicker.js"></script>            
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/dashboard.css" />
        <!-- ################ -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Top bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NY Noise Map</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Right Panel -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar"> 
                    <!-- Start Date -->
                    <form id="startDate" method="post" class="dateRangeForm form-vertical">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Start Date:</label>
                            <br></br>
                            <div class="date">
                                <div class="input-group input-append date dateRangePicker">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- End Date -->
                    <form id="endDate" method="post" class="dateRangeForm form-vertical">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">End Date:</label>
                            <br></br>
                            <div class="date">
                                <div class="input-group input-append date dateRangePicker">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
     </body>
```

This is the **datepicker.js** file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) 
        dd='0'+dd

    if (mm < 10) 
        mm='0'+mm

    today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

    $('.dateRangePicker')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            startDate: '01/01/2010',
            endDate: today
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // Revalidate the date field
            $('.dateRangeForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
        });

    $('.dateRangeForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            date: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The date is required'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        min: '01/01/2010',
                        max: today,
                        message: 'The date is not a valid'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I'm currently receiving this error:

```
TypeError: $('.dateRangeForm').formValidation is not a function. (In '$('.dateRangeForm').formValidation', '$('.dateRangeForm').formValidation' is undefined)
(anonymous function)datepicker.js:25
jjquery-2.1.0.min.js:1:26681
fireWithjquery-2.1.0.min.js:1:27490
readyjquery-2.1.0.min.js:1:29294
Ijquery-2.1.0.min.js:1:29458
```

And I don't know why.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it calling

```
bootstrapValidator
```

instead of

```
formValidation
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using  `$(document).load(function() {` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {`

also pass $ to `$(document).ready(function($) {` ready function if the above does not work.